# Perform a query without using cursors

Tags: sql, sql-server, impala

*I have a work table that contains information about clients, the loans you have and their amount owed, as well as the accounts and their balance. With this information I must present an additional column that indicates the amount to be debited based on the balance you have in the account and the amount owed. Considering that the information of the accounts of each client is repeated according to the number of loans that he has, and that it is not possible to indicate an amount to debit that exceeds the available one. 
This was solved using cursors, but I must use only SQL queries.
This would be a table with an example of the data:

[image: Data]

And the expected result would be as follows:
[image]

I have found alternatives using the over partition clause, but I am not sure how to apply it.
I am grateful for some idea of how I can address the problem.
I attach the table code with the data in case you want to run some solution.

```sql
    create table table_test(
    customer int,
    loand int,
    debt_amount money,
    account int,
    account_balance money,
    );
    truncate table table_test;
    insert into table_test values (1, 1, 5000, 1, 500);
    insert into table_test values (1, 1, 5000, 2, 400);
    insert into table_test values (1, 2, 3000, 1, 500);
    insert into table_test values (1, 2, 3000, 2, 400);

    insert into table_test values (2, 3, 1000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 4, 2000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 5, 3000, 3, 3000);
    insert into table_test values (2, 6, 4000, 3, 3000);

    insert into table_test values (3, 7, 9000, 4, 10000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 7, 9000, 5, 2000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 8, 7000, 4, 10000);
    insert into table_test values (3, 8, 7000, 5, 2000);

    select * from table_test;
```

The amount of `amount_to_debit` is the amount I must reattach from my account to pay off the loan debt.
The idea of these queries is to generate a report that tells me how much to deduct from customers' accounts to collect what they owe on their loans. If there is more debt and there is no longer available to debit, those rows should not be shown on the report.

Comment: "This was solved using cursors, but I must use only SQL queries" where is the Cursor ?

Comment: What version of `SQL Server` are you using ? Or you are using something else ?

Comment: @VBokšić One cursor runs through the client - loan table and another internal one runs through each client account. It accumulates the values to be debited.
I don't have it at hand. But the idea is that for each record is specified how much to debit the account to pay the debt. And if the money is no longer enough, do not show the other loans that are left with no amount to debit.

Comment: @Squirrel Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 10.0 <X64> (Build 18362: )

Comment: please show your current `cursor` query. And please update your question with the logic required

Comment: @Squirrel Try to explain the logic of the cursor, because I don't have the code of that cursor at hand.

Comment: please explain how to obtain the value for `amount_to_debit` ?

Comment: It would help if the column names matched the names used in  the question , what are the column names for  'the loans you have and their amount owed, as well as the accounts and their balance' and what is loand (it seems like a poinless inclusion) ALSO what does esta fila no se mostraria mean in english?